# Symfony 1.4 url_for empty string behavior

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm working on a Symfony 1.4 project and when I do this:

```
url_for('');
```

I'm expecting to get the URL for the `index.php` controller or at least `http://domain/` but I'm getting this:

```
/sfTCPDF
```

`sfTCPDF` is a plugin that I have in this project that in my `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` is used like:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration {
    public function setup() {
        $this->enablePlugins('sfTCPDFPlugin');
    }
}
```

When I disable the plugin I get the expected result:

```
$url = url_for('');
> /
```

Or when I use it like this (Doesn't matter if the plugin is enabled or not):

```
$url = url_for('/');
> /
```

I don't understand why the plugin is causing (or even if it's the plugin fault).

Any suggestions? I can search & replace the entire project for `url_for('')` and put the `'/'`
But I really want to understand why this is happening.

**After some research:**
I found out that when the `url_for` function is called, the procedure is the next:

- `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/UrlHelper.php url_for()`
- `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/UrlHelper.php url_for2()`
- `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/UrlHelper.php url_for1()`
- `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/controller/sfWebController.class.php gen_url()`
- `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php generate()`

And in the last one it gets the `$this->pattern` here is where the pattern is `sfTCPDF/:action`

which means that some routing is playing. Continuing my research i found out that the plugin has a `routing.yml` with:

```
sfTCPDF:
    url:   /sfTCPDF/:action
    param: { module: sfTCPDF, action: test }
```

If I delete this routing everything works as expected.

Now the question is: when do the plugin creates a routing object with the pattern of `sfTCPDF` and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url_for` uses the route name you provide to find the proper route in the cached routes table. If you provide an empty string it will take the `0` index from the table (which you can find in the file: `cache/app/env/config/config_routing.yml.php`.

When the TCPDF plugin is on its' route is being added as the first one that's why you get it as the url.

The solution - don't use an empty string for `url_for`. If you want to get the url of the homepage always use `url_for('/')` or `url_for('@homepage')`.

Comment: You explain the behaivor of symfony according of routing, that resolve my question! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I never use the url_for with an empty string.

In my routes file I use to have:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: home, action: index }
```

So if I want the route for this, I use:

```
url_for('@homepage');
```

Comment: It's also a good way to solve this.
But my question still is: why do the plugin is doing this?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess that using '' is not supported.
I've checked the symfony source code and there's a special case of '/' but not for '', so I guess the function is expecting to get some string.